# Function not available in Lib

Tags: c++

i started programming in c++.
I wrote one line code in c++ and i got an error which i cant solve.

In order to fix this problem i searched some internet pages but i cant find the solution to this problem.
Here is the Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout <<remainder(10 % 3.25) << endl;`
}
```

I cant execute this code. The failurelog says that the function  remainder and fmod cant be found. 
I also tried it out to include the math.h lib.

Can someone help me to fix my problem?

Many thanks 
Pat

Comment: *In order to fix this problem i searched some internet pages* -- The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder) shows remainder as taking two arguments.  The `%` operator doesn't make sense there.

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
cout <<remainder(10 , 3.25) << endl;
```

By `remainder(10 , 3.25)` you are passing 2 arguments to the function `remainder`.

`10 % 3.25` is not valid because the second argument for the operator `%` is double.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder

And there is no need for `#include <stdio.h>`

See [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)